# why does compiler print char as smilie

Tags: c++, cout

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a=1025;

    int *p=&a;
    cout<<"Size of integer is: "<<sizeof(int)<<" bytes"<<endl;
    cout<<"Address= "<<p<<" Value= "<<*p<<endl;

    char *p0;
    p0=(char*)p;
    cout<<"Size of char is: "<<sizeof(char)<<" bytes"<<endl;
    cout<<"Address= "<<p0<<"Value= "<<*p0<<endl;
    cout<<"It printed smilie above";

    return 0;
}
```

Why is the address and value of char printed as a smilie?

The output I got is:

```
Size of integer is: 4 bytes  
Address= 0x61ff04 Value= 1025
Size of char is: 1 bytes     
Address= ☺♦Value= ☺
```

Comment: What did you expect it to print?

Answer (score 1):

The [overload for `operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) which prints `char*` (like `char *p0;`) does not print the *address* the pointer is pointing at like the overload for `void*`. Instead, it actually reads the content at the pointed-out address - and keeps on reading, until a `\0` is encountered, which is what makes `std::cout << "Hello world";` work.

`"Hello world"` (a null terminated C string) in itself decays into a `const char*`, pointing at the `H`, and the `operator<<` overload starts reading there and outputs each character until it sees a `\0` and then it stops.

The smiley is just a happy coincidence. The values stored at the pointed-out address happened to form a unicode sequence - which forms a smiley.